# Je ne demande pas d' / les / des explications

Tags: articles

Bonjour,

> Il hausse les épaules :

> -- Ils me respecteront lorsque le temps viendra.
>
> Je ne comprends pas, mais je ne demande pas **d**’explications.

Est-ce qu'il faut utiliser ici l'article indéfini ou l'article défini "**les** explications que j'attends de lui" ? Est-il possible d'écrire "des" *je ne demande pas **des** explications* (aucune explication) ? Il serait alors possible d'imaginer en détail ces explications.

Answer (score 2):

La forme attendue ici est:

> je ne demande pas d’explications.

Les autres sont grammaticalement possibles mais ont un sens différent.

> [...] je ne demande pas les explications.

Ici, il semble que les explications existent et sont par exemple rédigées sur un papier, et on ne demande pas a voir ce papier. Ça peut aussi vouloir dire qu'il y a plusieurs explications et qu'on ne les demande pas.

> [...] je ne demande pas des explications.

Très improbable dans le contexte donné mais cette phrase signifierait que ce que je demande, c'est autre chose que des explications.

Comment: _[...] je ne demande pas **des** explications, mais votre obéissance_ Oui. Mais je crois que _Je ne demande pas des explications_ tout court signifie que je m'imagine davantage tous les détails de ces explications. Ce n'est pas vrai ?

Comment: Pas trop, dans ce cas, on dirait aussi *je ne demande pas d'explications*.

Answer (score 1):

Oui, il est possible d'écrire « des », mais évidemment le locuteur place la situation dans un autre contexte.  Si « des » est utilisé, alors une opposition est établie entre une situation antérieure possible mais non réalisée et une nouvelle situation. Il faut prendre les choses à leur début.

Il s'agit dans cette phrase de *l'usage de l'article indéfini dans les phrases négatives* (… **ne** demande **pas** …). Les explications sont tirées de [La Grammaitre pour l'étudiant finnophone](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html), dans laquelle on trouve des explications suivies.

**Modifications dans une phra­se né­ga­ti­ve**
Forme « *de* » devant complément de verbe direct (CVD) et su­jet post­po­sé

Quand l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni (tou­tes les for­mes, c’est-à-dire singulier, pluriel et massif) dé­ter­mi­ne un grou­pe no­mi­nal qui est com­plé­ment de ver­be direct (CVD) d’un ver­be à la for­me né­ga­ti­ve, il prend gé­né­ra­le­ment la for­me « **de** »   :

♦ J’ai **une** voiture. → Je n’ai pas en­co­re **de** voiture.
♦ J’ai remar­qué **des** fautes. → Je n’ai pas remar­qué **de** fautes.
♦ Nous n’avons pas appris **de** mots nouveaux.

L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni prend éga­le­ment la for­me « **de** » quand il dé­ter­mi­ne un groupe nominal su­jet post­po­sé d’un ver­be à la for­me né­ga­ti­ve d’une cons­truc­tion impersonnelle avec le pro­nom con­ju­ga­teur « **il** » (le su­jet occupe la mê­me position qu’un com­plé­ment de verbe direct) :

♦ Il faut **un** au­tre collaborateur. → Il ne faut pas **d**’au­tre collaborateur.
♦ Il reste en­co­re **du** fromage ? → Il ne reste plus **de** fromage.

la for­me de l’ar­ti­cle change en fran­çais dans la phra­se né­ga­ti­ve, mais cet ar­ti­cle exprime dans les deux cas la quan­ti­té ou la nature in­dé­fi­nie.
Cepen­dant, cette règle de la transformation de l’ar­ti­cle dans une phra­se né­ga­ti­ve ne s’applique pas sys­té­ma­ti­que­ment. L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni peut conserver sa for­me nor­ma­le dans les cas sui­vants.

**Néga­tion par­tielle**

L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni devant CVD d’une phra­se né­ga­ti­ve devient de quand la néga­tion est totale. Ex­em­ple : le lo­cu­teur devait acheter des pommes et ne l’a pas fait, il dit :

♦ Je n’ai pas acheté **de** pommes.

Donc il est revenu sans les pommes prévues, le com­plé­ment du ver­be est « nié » complètement (com­plé­ment = « zéro, rien »). De mê­me, dans la phra­se sui­vante, on dit que la police n’a rien trouvé qui puisse servir à accuser le suspect (com­plé­ment = « zéro, rien ») :

♦ La police n’a pas pu trouver **de** preuves contre le suspect.

Mais la néga­tion peut aus­si être partielle : le ver­be peut avoir un com­plé­ment, mais ce com­plé­ment est dif­fé­rent de celui prévu ou supposé. Dans ce cas, l’ar­ti­cle reste généralement à la for­me nor­ma­le « **des/du/de la/de** ». Dans la phra­se sui­vante, la per­son­ne a bien acheté quel­que chose, mais ce ne sont pas des pommes. Ce qui est nié est la nature du com­plé­ment, et non pas le com­plé­ment tout entier :

♦ Je n’ai pas acheté **des** pommes, j’ai acheté **des** cerises.

---

*Comment cela s'applique dans la phrase*

> Ils me respecteront lorsque le temps viendra.
> Je ne comprends pas, mais je ne demande pas **d**’explications.

« **Les** » n'est utilisé que si les explications sont définies dans le contexte ou si la personne qui parle sait ou reconnait que ce qui lui est dit est une série d'explications ; c'est un choix que cette personne peut faire. Mais si la personne ne voit dans les explications que des explications quelconques  elle utilise l'article indéfini (**des**). Seulement, comme la phrase est négative « des » est remplacé par « de ».

Voyons comment « des » pourrait être utilisé.

— Je dois d'abord savoir de quel droit vous voulez fouiller.
— Nous allons vous expliquer pourquoi nous devons perquisitionner chez vous.
— Je ne vous demande pas **des** explications, ce que je vous demande c'est de me montrer le mandat de perquisition.

Dans le dialogue ci-dessus ce qui est nié ce n'est pas qu'une demande a été faite ; ce qui est nié c'est que cette demande aurait été une demande d'explications ; c'est une dmande (bien qu'implicitement formulée) mais c'est une demande d'autre chose (demande de papiers).

*Autre exemple*

— Alors vous leur avez donné **des** explications sur la marche à suivre ?
— Nous ne leur avons pas donné **des** explications mais **des** plans, c'est ce qu'ils avaient demandé.

Comment: Merci :) pour votre explication.